# Java-Calculator more than one calculation

Tags: java

I have written a code for a calculator but it is not working 100% reliably,yet.   Every time I do a calculation, for example: "1+1=2", and I want to do another calculation I have to close the applet and start it again.  How can I make it go back at the start.

Here is the code:

```
package beispiele;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class Kalkulator extends Applet {
    String arg1= "", arg2="";
    int ergebnis;
    Button zahl[] =new Button[10];
    Button funktion[] = new Button[4];
    Button ausfuehren;
    Panel zahlPanel,funktionPanel,ergebnisPanel;
    TextField ergebnisFeld;
    int operationArgument;
    char operation;
    public void init () {
    operationArgument= 1; operation =' ';
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    zahlPanel = new Panel();
    zahlPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout (4,3));
    for (int i=9; i>=0; i--) {
        zahl[i] = new Button(String.valueOf(i));
        zahl[i].addActionListener(new ButtonZahlen());
        zahlPanel.add(zahl[i]);
    }
    zahlPanel.add(new Button("."));   //leere Taste
    ausfuehren = new Button("=");
    ausfuehren.addActionListener(new ButtonAusfuehren()); //zu dem Listener
    zahlPanel.add(ausfuehren);
    add("Center",zahlPanel);
    funktionPanel = new Panel();
    funktionPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));
    funktion[0] = new Button("+");
    funktion[0].addActionListener(new ButtonOperation());
    funktionPanel.add(funktion[0]);
    funktion[1] = new Button("-");
    funktion[1].addActionListener(new ButtonOperation());
    funktionPanel.add(funktion[1]);
    funktion[2] = new Button("*");
    funktion[2].addActionListener (new ButtonOperation());
    funktionPanel.add(funktion[2]);
    funktion[3] = new Button("/");
    funktion[3].addActionListener (new ButtonOperation());
    funktionPanel.add(funktion[3]);

    //funktionPanel.add(new Button("*"));
    //funktionPanel.add(new Button("/"));
    add("East",funktionPanel);
    ergebnisPanel = new Panel();
    ergebnisFeld = new TextField("0",5);
    ergebnisPanel.add(ergebnisFeld);
    add("North",ergebnisPanel);
}
class ButtonZahlen implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch (operationArgument)   {
        case 1 :  {
            arg1+=e.getActionCommand();
            ergebnisFeld.setText(arg1);
            break;
        }
        case 2 :   {
            arg2 +=e.getActionCommand();
            ergebnisFeld.setText(arg2);
            break;
        }
        default: { }

        }
        }
    }
class ButtonAusfuehren implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(operation =='+')
            if (arg1.equals("")) {
                ergebnis += new Integer(arg2);
            } else {
                ergebnis = new Integer(arg1) + new Integer(arg2);
            }

        else if(operation =='-') {
            if(arg1.equals("")) {
                ergebnis -= new Integer(arg2);
            } else {
                ergebnis = new Integer(arg1) - new Integer(arg2);
            }               
        }
        else if(operation =='*') {
            if(arg1.equals("")) {
                ergebnis *= new Integer(arg2);
            } else {
                ergebnis = new Integer(arg1) * new Integer(arg2);
            }
        }
        else if(operation =='/') {
            if(arg1.equals("")) {
                ergebnis *= new Integer(arg2);
            } else {
                ergebnis = new Integer(arg1) / new Integer(arg2);
            }
        }
    }
}
class ButtonOperation implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("+")) {
            operation = '+'; operationArgument = 2;
            }
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("-")) {
                operation = '-'; operationArgument = 2;
                }
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("*")) {
                    operation = '*' ; operationArgument =2;
                    }
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("/")) {
                        operation = '/' ; operationArgument =2;
                    }

            }
        }
public void paint(Graphics g){   }


}
```

Comment: actually, there is usually a C button on calculators, that clears all the previous calculations and restarts it all

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Comment: I have seen such button,but I have no idea how to do it.That was the reason to ask for help.
I am using applet and awt,because that is what the teacher wants.Which is a problem,because it is hard to find detailed information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having problems here because you are not careful with your if and else statements and the logic of the program. Firstly, in the `actionPerformed` method of `ButtonOperation`, you have an `if(e.getActionCommand().equals("-"))` **inside** the `if(e.getActionCommand().equals("+"))`. That doesn't make sense, does it? The commands you are testing for with those ifs are mutually exclusive, so an `else if` for the - operation is what you want. Then in the `ButtonAusfuehren` `actionPerformed()` method: again, think about what you want to be doing. You don't need the last else - you can always set the result field (`ergebnisFeld`) to the result. Also, the operations themselves wouldn't have worked as the second time an operation was done, one of the arguments (`arg1` or `arg2`) would have been an empty string. If you take this into account, you get something like this, which, with the other changes, makes your calculator work:

```
        if (operation == '+')
            if (arg1.equals("")) {
                ergebnis += new Integer(arg2);
            } else {
                ergebnis = new Integer(arg1) + new Integer(arg2);
            }

        else if (operation == '-') {
            if (arg1.equals("")) {
                ergebnis -= new Integer(arg2);
            } else {
                ergebnis = new Integer(arg1) - new Integer(arg2);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Martin,thank you for the really quick and detailed answer.It really helped clearing some missunderstandings,but still the "=" button doesn't work.I edited my code here with the new changes in ButtonAusfuehren and ButtonOperation